# Save workspace with terminal command and execute when opened

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I'm working in a project with Django and Vue, everyday when I open VSCode I have to manually open 3 terminals, one for running `livereload server`, the second for `django server (runserver)` and the third to execute `webpack`.

My VSCode crashes several times a day and I have to restart it, and I spend a lot of time doing it every time.

Is there a way to save the terminals configuration in the workspace and force VSCode to execute the commands they were executing when I closed it? I've not found a visual-studio-task or estension which satisfies my need.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60621321/restore-terminals-with-commands-in-vscode/60665510#60665510 it may work for you.   A way to open multiple terminals and run different commands in each, question was about onFolderOpen but it could assigned to a keybinding instead.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried but it doesn't work for me as expected, I'm waiting the author response.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Restore Terminals](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EthanSK.restore-terminals) extension.

```
  "restoreTerminals.runOnStartup": false,   // true is the default
          // set to false if using a keybinding or command palette

  "restoreTerminals.terminals": [
    {
      "splitTerminals": [
        {
          "name": "livereload",
          "commands": [
            "<command to start live reload server>"   // not in brackets
          ]
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      "splitTerminals": [
        {
          "name": "django",
          "commands": [
            //  "cd <another folder>",  // if necessary
            "<your runserver command here>"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "splitTerminals": [
        {
          "name": "webpack",
          "commands": [
            "start webpack"   // whatever the command is
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
```

It can auto-run on start or you can trigger it with a keybinding like:

```
{
  "key": "shift+alt+t",    // whatever keybinding if you wish
  "command": "restore-terminals.restoreTerminals",
},
```

---

If you are using Windows, I highly recommend this setting:

```
"terminal.integrated.windowsEnableConpty": false,
```

until this bug gets fixed: [Closing a conpty terminal can hang the window](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/76548#event-3057575501)
.

Answer (score 0):

The **Tasks feature** is the current recommended way to handle this and works very well for me. See [Automating launching of terminals](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_automating-launching-of-terminals) in the VS Code documentation.